# Pandas dataframe change all value if greater than 0

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df=

A    B    C
1    2    55
0    44    0
0    0    0
```

and I want to change values to 1 if the value is >0.

Is this the right approach:
df.loc[df>0,]=1

```
to give: 
A    B    C
1    1    1
0    1    0
0    0    0
```

Comment: Are you after `df.loc[df.gt(0).all(1), :] = 1` ?

Comment: Just tried it and that didn't work but thanks for trying. Any other ideas?

Comment: well, that's if all values are >0 for  row, if you just want to max each value then `df.clip_upper(1)`? Your question title and body don't seem to be quite in tandem with what you might be asking.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`clip_upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip_upper.html):

```
df = df.clip_upper(1)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
```

Numpy alternative:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.clip(df.values, a_min=0, a_max=1), 
                  index=df.index, 
                  columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
```

And solution if no negative integer values - compare by [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) (`>=`) and cast mask to integers:

```
print (df.ge(1))
       A      B      C
0   True   True   True
1  False   True  False
2  False  False  False

df = df.ge(1).astype(int)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df.clip_upper(1)
```

or this:

```
df.where(df < 1, other=1)
```

Comment: Yes to the first - but it's not equivalent to the second...

Comment: This is great but there is a added complication that the value in question will not always be 0. It might be 20.

Comment: I've tried this df=np.where(df<20,df==0,df==1)

Comment: but that returns an array

Comment: df[df< 20] = 0
df[df!= 0] = 1

Comment: I can do it in 2 lines